# Wordpress dashboard and my WordPress website not opening

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress dashboard and my WordPress website not opening.
Yesterday it was working fine but today its not working. I havent edited any thing. When i open the page it shows this error.

```html
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"        "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml">   
       
       <wml>
          <card id = "not_found" title = "Error 504">
            <p>  Origin Server returned 504 Status </p> 
          </card>
       </wml>
```

My website. www.store.codebla.com

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a proxy server involved in your installation. The error message with [code 504](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) origins from that. The server with the actual WordPress installation is maybe down, at least the proxy server cannot reach it and then returns this error.

Talk to your provider to get support.